# Is it possible to create a formula that locks a range using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to lock a range of cells based on another cell's value. This is obviously impossible using worksheet functions, and subs only run at click.
Can I create a formula that locks cells with VBA? I tried this but the formula returns #VALUE! error.

```
Function lo(range)
lo(range) = range.Select
Selection.Locked = True
End Function
```

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your question is No. You can try to use `Worksheet_Events` (e.g. Worksheet_Change) By this, routine fires everytime a certain event took place. Events are reference (Byval) with certain Objects you can evaluate to use in your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

**Sheet1 Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value <> 1 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Important:** You have to set all cells locked property to False by default.

**Thisworkbook code:** For above to work, you have to add another event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True
    'Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Protect userinterfaceonly:= True
End Sub
```

What above does is protect Sheet1. I used its code name although it can be written also using the commented line.
Sheet1 is where you set up all cells locked property to false.
So everytime you enter something in a cell, if it is not 1, the adjacent cell will be locked for editting.
Hope this somehow help your purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to deal with the problem with your solution.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Thanks.